# wp_menu in wordpress php function

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I'm trying to create a simple nav in wordpress, however the **wp_nav_menu** parameters are ignored , am I missing something obvious?

I'm using a blank template called html5 blank. The Steps i've taken so are listed below

1) Register the menu in functions.php

2) From word press back end  Create a menu called 'p' and assign pages

3) Give the menu a theme location

Registering and assigning menu location work fine , some but for some reason the wp_ parameters are ignored EG  container , menu class, menu id etc...

If i inspect element, the container 'nav' is missing and the li items have default word press classes

---

BELOW is my code

**Code in header.php**

```
<?php html5blank_nav() ?>
```

**Code in functions.php**

```
function html5blank_nav()
    {
        wp_nav_menu(
        array(
            'theme_location'  => 'primary pete',    
            'menu'            => 'p'
            'container'       => 'nav',
            'container_class' => '',
            'container_id'    => '',
            'menu_class'      => 'slimmenu',
            'menu_id'         => 'navigation',
            'echo'            => true,
            'fallback_cb'     => 'false',
            'before'          => '',
            'after'           => '',
            'link_before'     => '',
            'link_after'      => '',
            'items_wrap'      => '<ul>%3$s</ul>',
            'depth'           => 0,
            'walker'          => ''
            )
        );
    }
```

// Register HTML5 Blank Navigation

```
  function register_html5_menu()
        {
            register_nav_menus(array( // Using array to specify more menus if needed
                'primary' => __('primary pete', 'Primary Menu'), 

                'sidebar-menu' => __('Sidebar Menu', 'html5blank'), 

                'extra-menu' => __('Extra Menu', 'html5blank') 
            ));
    }




// Remove the <div> surrounding the dynamic navigation to cleanup markup
function my_wp_nav_menu_args($args = '')
{
    $args['container'] = false;
    return $args;
}





// Remove Injected classes, ID's and Page ID's from Navigation <li> items
function my_css_attributes_filter($var)
{
    return is_array($var) ? array() : '';
}

// Remove invalid rel attribute values in the categorylist
function remove_category_rel_from_category_list($thelist)
{
    return str_replace('rel="category tag"', 'rel="tag"', $thelist);
}

// Add page slug to body class, love this - Credit: Starkers Wordpress Theme
function add_slug_to_body_class($classes)
{
    global $post;
    if (is_home()) {
        $key = array_search('blog', $classes);
        if ($key > -1) {
            unset($classes[$key]);
        }
    } elseif (is_page()) {
        $classes[] = sanitize_html_class($post->post_name);
    } elseif (is_singular()) {
        $classes[] = sanitize_html_class($post->post_name);
    }

    return $classes;
}
```

Many thanks,
P

Answer (score 0):

When i try to reproduce this the menu with container_class => 'slimmenu' is shown.
Are you sure when you add a class to the container_class parameter this is not shown in the inspector?

Also noticed a missing comma after the parameter 'p' when i copied your code. But i don't think it will resolve your problem.